# Why does the same function do 2 different things?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I'm an Amateur at C# and I don't understand what's going on here. It's not really a problem, as I can make a quickfix for it, but I still want to know **Why**.

*Disclaimer*: I know this is probably not the best way to design this program, but I have been given a very short amount of time to develop it and I'm just trying to ship it by the deadline.

I have a main form in my program. This form calls a second form when 1 of 2 buttons are pressed. These buttons use the same function to open the second form:

```
private void setupShow(int show)
    {
        fSetup setup = new fSetup(show);
        setup.Show();
        setup.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(setup_FormClosed);
    }
```

When button1 calls that function, it hides the main form and opens the next form. However, when the second button calls that function it keeps the main form open, but still opens the second form.

So what could be causing this?

*Button1 has quite a bit more code than button2 and if the functions are needed, I can post them here but it would fill up the majority of the screen.*

Edit:

```
int show;
```

Is just a variable I use for functions performed in the second form. It has no bearing on anything as far as windows closing.

Button 1: Only calls this function. The function inserts into a database, then gets the inserted ID of that row and passes it to the second form

```
private void CheckFields()
    {
        OleDbCommand insertParty;
        OleDbDataAdapter partyAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        int nameL = PName.Text.Length;
        int newPartyID = 0;

        if (nameL > 0)
        {
            String test = "INSERT INTO Parties (PartyName, BackgroundImg) VALUES (?, ?)";

            insertParty = new OleDbCommand(test, Parties);
            insertParty.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartyName", PName.Text);
            insertParty.Parameters.AddWithValue("BackgroundImg", tBrowse.Text);


            Parties.Open();
            insertParty.ExecuteNonQuery();

            NewPartyForm.ActiveForm.Visible = false;


            OleDbCommand selectnewParty;
            OleDbDataAdapter newpartyAdaptr = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            String selectNew = "SELECT TOP 1 PartyID, PartyName FROM Parties ORDER BY PartyID DESC";
            selectnewParty = new OleDbCommand(selectNew, Parties);
            OleDbDataReader newReader = selectnewParty.ExecuteReader();

            while (newReader.Read())
            {
                newPartyID = newReader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            setupShow(newPartyID);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Create a Party Name");
    }
```

Button 2:  Cuts out the integer from the string in a combobox and passes it to the second form

```
private void bLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object selectedParty = cLoadP.SelectedItem;
        String sP = selectedParty.ToString();
        String d1 = " - ";
        char[] delim = d1.ToCharArray();
        String[]  numS = sP.Split(delim);

        setupShow(Convert.ToInt32(numS[0]));
    }
```

Like I said, this code is being developed by an amateur and very quickly. This is not the way I would normally do things, but I don't have much time to really think. lol

Second form initial function:

```
public fSetup(int partyID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pID = partyID;
        lpID.Text += " " + pID.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The explanation is not in the code you posted, please post all the relevant code

Comment: A key to troubleshooting/debugging is determining relevant code. If you trim it to a length worth posting here, I'd wager you'll find the answer.

Comment: I would closely examine the meaning and the usage of the `int show` parameter that is passed to the `fSetup` constructor.

Comment: too painful to look at - try what @JohnArlen suggested

Comment: Can you also post the code for `setup_FormClosed` ? Perhaps the logic is in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the cause of the different behavior is this line in the code for button 1:

```
NewPartyForm.ActiveForm.Visible = false;
```

There's no similar line in the code for button 2.

Comment: This is the second idiot move I've made on this project. I looked over it several times and couldn't figure out where I was hiding it. lol

Comment: @NSGaga Thanks. It was mostly luck. After reading your "too painful to look at" comment, I decided to look at the code to see how painful it really was.  As I was coming to the conclusion that it was in fact painful, I happened to notice that line.